# Rails with Jader gets 'failed to require "fs"' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pug

I am trying to use client side Jade templates that are precompiled by Ruby on Rails and available through JST.

I added the jader gem

`gem "jader", "~> 0.0.8"`

In configuration/initializers I created an initializer called jader.rb that contains:

```
Jader.configure do |config|
  config.views_path = Rails.root.join('app','assets','javascripts','views')
  config.mixins_path = Rails.root.join('app','assets','javascripts','mixins')
end
```

In app/assets/javascripts/views I added an index.js.jst.jade file

```
Hello World!
```

Lastly in my javascript file I have:

```
$('#app-content').append(JST["views/index"]());
```

When I run Rails and browse to the page triggering the code I am getting the following error:

```
failed to require "fs"
  (in /my-project/app/assets/javascripts/views/index.js.jst.jade)
```

I understand that the problem is that jade is a node.js project and the require function is having a problem.  How do I fix the require error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at using Jade templates only on the client side (with Rails asset pipeline), I recommend https://github.com/inossidabile/jade

Answer (score 0):

It's likely there is an error in your index.jade template. 
From the [jade rails-fix pull request here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/pull/794), ExecJS used by rails does not support require("fs") and will throw 'failed to require "fs" even if it's a template error. Hopefully this should point you in the right direction.

To debug, you can replace the content of index.jade template with with a 1-liner jade placeholder to see if it renders well. Alternatively, try it out rendering the index.jade template with a nodejs server if possible to be sure the template renders without any whinning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The one line jade file I am using as explained above is "Hello World!" which renders to "<Hello>World!</Hello>" so it doesn't seem to be a template error.